# Operating on byte[] and int[], the same memory

Tags: java, android, performance

I am looking to speed up my program. Currently I have a function that does this:

```
public void updateBitmap(byte[] buf, int thisPacketLength, int standardOffset, int thisPacketOffset) {      
    int pixelCoord = thisPacketOffset / 3 - 1;
    for (int bufCoord = standardOffset; bufCoord < thisPacketLength; bufCoord += 3) {
        pixelCoord++;
        pixelData[pixelCoord] = 0xFF << 24 | (buf[bufCoord + 2] << 16) & 0xFFFFFF | (buf[bufCoord + 1] << 8) & 0xFFFF | buf[bufCoord] & 0xFF;           
    }
}
```

I basically need to copy ints in `byte[]` form into an `int[]` array. I realized that if I can treat the `int[]` array as a byte array then I can simply modify the bytes directly, instead of doing all this shifting, which I imagine would be faster. However, I can't figure out how to do that.

What I want is to have `int[] pixelData` and `byte[] pixelDataBytes` both point to the memory. Just be two different "views" of the same bits in memory if you understand what I mean. Then I can update the individual bytes as they come in without shifting them, while still maintaining the `int[]` representation I need for other parts of the code. It seems like this should be possible, but I haven't figured out how to do it yet.

Comment: Don't forget that by doing this you may get endianness problems. Fortunately, `ByteBuffer` allows to select the `ByteOrder`.

Comment: @maaartinus I never knew that. Thanks for informing us!

Answer (score 3):

You should use a byte buffer instead. You can then access its backing as an int buffer, and read/write byte by byte or int by int,

Create it with:

```
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(buf);
```

and get an IntBuffer:

```
IntBuffer ib = bb.asIntBuffer();
```

You can set values in this buffer by writing to an index:

```
ib.put(2, 400);
```

were 2 is the index and 400 is the value. Any changes to `ib` will be backed by `bb` and `buf`.

Comment: Unfortunately on my android device I get java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException on int[] test = ib.array(). I need to have a reference to the integer array itself, not just be able to modify it using the IntBuffer. any suggestions?

Comment: @Trevor You can read it out int by int into an array of the same size.

Comment: yes I could do that, but that would defeat the purpose of what I'm doing. I want to have the int array and byte array point to the same memory. So doing byte[0] = ... would have an effect on int[0] and vice versa